# Quadratic extension of biquadratic extension Galois over base

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

We have the following setup: $K$ is a field of odd characteristic, $L$ is a biquadratic extension. We have already shown that $L = K( \sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b})$ for $a,b, a/b$ nonsquares in $K^\times$. The problem is the following:

> Let $c \in L^\times$ be a nzonsquare, and let $E = L ( \sqrt{c})$. Prove that $E$ is Galois over $K$ if and only if for each $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(L/K)$ the ratio $\sigma(c)/c$ is a square in $L$.

I'm honestly not sure how to approach either direction. For the forward direction, I was hoping that $E/K$ being Galois would imply that $\tau(\sigma(c)/c)) = c/\sigma(c)$ for all $\tau \in \text{Gal}(L/K)$. But, I can't see where the hypothesis that $E/K$ is Galois comes in.

For the reverse direction, I was also hoping that I could somehow get the hypothesis that $\sigma(c)/c$ is a square to imply that $E$ is the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $c$ over $K$. But, this also seems hard and I don't know how to approach it. The separable part of showing Galois-ness is already handled, since the composition of separable extensions is separable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mean $\tau\in \operatorname{Gal}(E/K)$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbf{Q}}$

Let $G = \text{Gal}(L/K)$. Note that:

$\sigma(c)/c$ is a square in $L$ for all $\sigma \in G$

$\Longleftrightarrow$ $L(\sqrt{c}) = L(\sqrt{\sigma(c)})$ for all $\sigma \in G$

$\Longleftrightarrow$ $\sqrt{\sigma(c)} \in L(\sqrt{c})$ for all $\sigma \in G$

$\Longleftrightarrow$ $\pm \sqrt{\sigma(c)} \in L(\sqrt{c})$ for all $\sigma \in G$ and for all choices of $\pm$

This last condition looks a bit silly, but notice that the Galois conjugates of $\sqrt{c}$ are exactly the $\pm \sqrt{\sigma(c)}$ for $\sigma \in G$. Indeed, if $x$ is a conjugate of $\sqrt{c}$ then $x^2$ is a conjugate of $c$, so $x^2 = \sigma(c)$ and $x$ has the desired form. Conversely, if $\sigma \in G$ then we can lift it to an element of $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ (or to the Galois group of the Galois closure of $E$ over $K$ if you prefer) where it now acts on $\sqrt{c}$, and $\sigma(\sqrt{c})^2 = \sigma(\sqrt{c}^2) = \sigma(c)$, so $\sigma(\sqrt{c})$ must be one of the square roots of $\sigma(c)$. Since $c$ is not a square, we know that its two square roots are conjugate to each other as well. This establishes the ``notice that'' from the start of this paragraph.

So if $E/K$ is Galois, then it certainly contains all the Galois conjugates of $\sqrt{c}$, so by the chain of equivalences above we are done. The converse is slightly more subtle since we need to account for the fact that $E$ might not be the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{c}$ over $K$. (For example, what if $c \in K$?) But supposing that $E = L(\sqrt{c})$ contains all the Galois conjugates of $\sqrt{c}$, we can conclude that $E$ is the compositum of $L$ and the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{c}$ over $K$, both of which are Galois.

As a final remark, notice that we never actually used that $L$ was biquadratic, only that it was Galois over $K$. Essentially this condition is asking if, from the point of view of $K$, the extension $L(\sqrt{c})$ is ``well-defined''. Let's think about $\Q$ for a second. $\Q$ can't tell $i$ and $-i$ apart, but $\Q(i) = \Q(-i)$ so that field is still Galois over $\Q$ because it contains all the conjugates of $i$. However, if we replace $i$ by $\sqrt[3]{2}$ (the real one), we see that $\Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ doesn't contain the other Galois conjugates of $\sqrt[3]{2}$, and the fields generated by each of these conjugates are isomorphic but not literally equal as subfields of $\overline{\Q}$. Consequently, $\Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not Galois over $\Q$. This is essentially what's happening in your problem as well, with $i$ or $\sqrt[3]{2}$ replaced by $\sqrt{c}$.

Comment: Why would $c\in K$ prevent $E$ to be the splitting field of the minpoly of $\sqrt{c}$ if that's what you're implying with your remark in parentheses. However, it seems to me that for finite $K$ adjoining the square roots  of two nonsquare elements of $K$ pulls in the roots of all the other nonsquare elements, too. At least that's what I get up to $\mathbb{F}_{13}$. That would mean that $K$ can't be finite in which case (since the characteristic is greater then 0) it would be a field of rational functions whose extension can be inseparable, i.e. non Galois. It's that what you had in mind?

Comment: Actually, if you adjoin one root $\alpha$ of a nonsquare element of odd char finite $K$ to $K$ then all $f\in K$ are squares in $K(\alpha)$: $x^2-f=0\Leftrightarrow (a+b\alpha)^2=f\Leftrightarrow a^2+2ab\alpha+\alpha^2=f$. As $\alpha^2 \in K$, $f$ can be expressed in terms of elements of $K(\alpha)$.

Comment: Yes, that's true: Once you add in one square root of a nonsquare to a finite field, you get all other square roots. I'm not seeing how that's relevant to my example, though. Let $K = \mathbf{Q}$ and $a = 2, b = 3$ so that $L = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$. Let $c = 5$. The splitting field of $\sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ is $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ whereas $E = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$. For an example in odd characteristic, let $K = \mathbf{F}_3(t)$ and choose $a = t$, $b = t-1$, and $c = t-2$. Inseparability isn't an issue here; all extensions are degree a power of $2$.

Comment: The $\mathbb{Q}$ example is perfectly clear. What I can't get my head around is how $E/K$ **can't** be Galois. If $K$ is finite then $E=L$ as we have just discussed so the only candidate is something like $F_q(t)$. I have almost no knowledge about extensions of this kind of field apart from the fact that it is the only (or at least a very rare) example of a possible inseparable extension. So is your example of $E/K$ with $E=\mathbb{F}_3(t,\sqrt{t},\sqrt{t-1},\sqrt{t-2})$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ indeed not Galois?

Comment: In that final example, $E/K$ is definitely Galois. If $c \in K$ then $E/K$ will always be Galois, it just might not be the splitting field of $\sqrt{c}$. My initial answer gives a way to construct some $E$ that's not Galois over $K$, just find some $c \in L$ that doesn't satisfy "$\sigma(c)/c$ is a square". Take $K = \mathbb{F}_3(t)$, $L = K(\sqrt{t}, \sqrt{t-1})$, and $c = \sqrt{t} \in L$. Then $E = K(\sqrt[4]{t}, \sqrt{t-1})$ isn't Galois over $K$ because $K$ doesn't have a 4th root of unity.